# Происхождение слова "куролесить"

Tags: этимология

"Куролесить" — дебоширить, проказничать. А откуда это слово взялось? Тут явно просматричаются "куры" и "лес")))

Answer (score 1):

От старинного *куралес*  - искаж. греч. kyrie eleison (Господи помилуй!).

"Идут лесом, поют куралесом, несут деревянный пирог с мясом" (отгадка: похороны)